# Does the DC component of any signal also carry information?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, fourier, system

Every signal carries some types of information in it. Mathematically we Know from Fourier series that these signals can be represented as a sum of its DC component and all the harmonics of fundamental frequency.

If somehow some part of the DC component of a signal gets lost, can we still assume that the information the signal carries still doesn't change (only energy of signal changes, or is it possible in any case that the loss of the DC component of signal actually causes loss of information from the signal?

Comment: Are you talking about signals *before* they are modulated or *after* they are modulated?

Comment: Generally speaking a single frequency (0Hz or other value) doesn't convey information (in some sense); a finite bandwidth is required. [A related theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem)

Comment: The value of DC carries some information but only if intended, such as an AGC or RSSI signal

Comment: You could associate any given "symbol" of your communication with a given DC magnitude. The tricky part begins when sending a *sequence* of such symbols. Then you end up abstracting "piece-wise DC" signals and end up reinventing the wheel with PAM (pulse-amplitude modulation).

Comment: Trouble is, DC assumes infinite timespan. I don't know of any electronics that have achieved that.

Comment: @glen_geek It's too late to achieve it now. We're past the beginning of time. Not just infinite time into the future but into the past as well.

Comment: If it carries information, it isn't DC.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Infinity always starts... right now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A fixed DC signal has information - the DC offset - that would be lost if it were blocked (that is, reset to 0V potential.) The bandwidth of that information is nevertheless 0Hz.

This idea comes up in information coding, such as the DCT used in JPEG. Each block is assigned a block-average DC offset at the beginning, and subsequent components are coded relative to that offset. This optimizes the ‘AC’ data values to be smaller and thus can have shorter codes to represent them.

Comment: Also of note: there are many modulation schemes which *explicitly* do not have any information on the DC component.  They change the symbols around to ensure that the DC component is 0.  This permits all sorts of things, such as using filtering capacitors.

Comment: But that’s not what we’re talking about here. Counter-example: satellite LNB switches that carry both the downconverted signal and a DC voltage to not only power the LNB, but also to select the signal polarity type.

Comment: So whether DC has information content to it is really is modulation scheme dependent.  You can make schemes which put some information there.  You can make schemes that do not.

Comment: A ‘DC-free’ coding scheme has an assumed average offset of zero. But it still has an offset value.

Comment: It has an offset value, but does that value convey information?

Comment: Only if the channel wants or needs it, like DCT for example.

Answer (score 7):

There is pretty much nothing special about the DC bin, since it integrates frequencies *around* 0 Hz, the bandwidth is dependent on the FFT length, as for the other bins. So it is possible to encode information there in the same way as for the others.

The reason it would not be used is usually based on some property of the transmission channel:

1. the channel has band-pass characteristics and filters out low frequencies: this is true for pretty much any wireless transmission, but also applies to several high-speed wired standards that have capacitors inline, like SATA, or couple the signal with transformers, like Ethernet.
2. the channel's frequency response isn't flat near lower frequencies: the variation in gain and phase response between two frequencies is usually higher if there is a large ratio between them, which is why you find wideband applications at higher frequencies.
3. the transmission channel uses DC for something else: this applies to the phone network, which distributes power over the phone line as well, and the DC polarity is important for minimizing corrosion on older lines as well.
4. the transmission channel introduces noise at or near the DC bin: for example, wireless transmission systems that use direct I/Q modulation will usually see DC offsets introduced by the analog-digital conversion, and less-than perfect carrier suppression, which makes the DC bin unusable (which is why LTE reserves the channel around the center frequency).

Comment: the phone network also uses DC for signalling on-hook/off-hook.

Answer (score 3):

Thought mine could go to the comment, but found I have my own answer as well.

See [this from stanford.edu](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/engr/engr40m.1178/slides/signals.pdf).

> the DC component is like the “zero frequency component”, since
> cos(2π·0·t) = 1.  We oftenthink of offset in this way, and plot the DC
> offset atf= 0 in the frequency-domain representation.The DC component
> is often easy to eyeball—it’s equal to the average value of the signal
> over a period.

Your question:

> If somehow some part of the DC component of a signal gets lost, can we
> still assume that the information the signal carries still doesn't
> change (only energy of signal changes, or is it possible in any case
> that the loss of the DC component of signal actually causes loss of
> information from the signal?

My answer:
"Average value of the signal" does not necessarily mean the "energy" (only), in my opinion. So, I would assume that change in the "Average value of the signal" implies change in the signal/information.

---

Edit

NRZ signals can have significant and meaningful DC components.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can transfer information using the whole bandwidth as you see fit.

You might use the low frequency DC component of a wire to control a device on or off, and then use the high frequency AC component of a wire to transfer data.

For example, HDMI uses the DC state of hotplug signal for detecting if a TV is connected or not, but the same wire can also be used as a differential high speed audio return channel.

Another example is the plain old telephone signaling - the DC signaling is used to determine if the phone is on-hook or off-hook, and the AC signal is used for voice transfer.

Obviously, with DC above, I mean DC in a time frame that makes sense in the usage of it, not DC regarding during a week as it would be AC signal compared to life of known universe.

I just realized that the above just described Power over Ethernet too.

Comment: PoE does not really use the data channel for power transfer

Comment: @jsotola so even if the same wires carry both data and power, you don't count that?

Comment: no I do not ... my understanding is that the DC component is invisible to the data channel ... if the data was superimposed on the power supply voltage, then it would be a different story

Comment: @jsotola Well, one pair of two wires carries DC supply current into device, and another pair of two wires carry the DC current return path out of the device. The current difference between the wires within a pair of wires has data. Well, good thing that's not the only example - for simplicity satellite dishes and CoaXpress cameras use single coaxial cable for power and data.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a modulation scheme which puts information into the DC component, or you can have one that does not.  Its quite common to explicitly design modulation schemes to not have any information in the DC component so that you can put bypass capacitors on the signal lines.

That being said, we're going to have to question the meaning of "DC".  In practical environments with noise, the [Shannon-Hartley Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) applies, and we find that a channel with 0 bandwidth, whether it's DC or 1000Hz, cannot carry any information.  You need a range, such as 0-1Hz or 1000-1001Hz.  So in that sense, the DC offset cannot carry information (or, perhaps more exacting: carries an infinitesimal amount of information).

In practical situations where we are talking about "DC" we're really talking about signals that vary so slowly that we haven't been able to detect their change.  You're almost 100% guaranteed to have some change in the "DC" voltage when you plug things in.  But for all intents and purposes, anything longer than a few thousand symbols in length is going to be considered DC-ish.  And whether information is put in that range is a practical question for any given modulation.